# Getting id of td

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to get the id of this td.... When I check my network console it says id=undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong......

```
<td data-id="' . $fetch['userID'] . '" >
    <button onClick = "deleterecord();">delete</button>
</td>
```

javascript

```
function deleterecord() {

     //var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
     var del_id = $(this).closest('td').data('id');
     var dataString = 'id=' + del_id;

     if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "deletemember.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                opacity: "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
}
```

deletemember.php

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE li.*
                           FROM `loginInfo` li
                           WHERE li.userID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt){
        header('Location: memberinfo.php');       
    } else echo 'Delete failed. Try again';
```

Comment: `<td data-id="' . $fetch['userID'] . '" >
    <button onClick = "deleterecord('".$fetch['userID']."');">delete</button>
</td>` and `function deleterecord(ID) {`

Comment: @Rayon Just tried doesn't work

Comment: First impression is - you don't find the `id` of the `td` as there is no property of `td` called `id`. better your try with `attr('data-id')`.

Comment: bind your onclick from JS instead of in HTML and it will work: you need `this`

Comment: @dandavis How do I do that? Could you give an example?

Comment: lookup "delegated events"

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <button onClick = "deleterecord('123');">delete</button>
</td>
```

**javascript**

```
function deleterecord(userID) {

     if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "deletemember.php",
                data: {userID:userID},
                success: function () {
                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                opacity: "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
```

**deletemember.php**

```
$id = $_POST['userID'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE li.*
                           FROM `loginInfo` li
                           WHERE li.userID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt){
        header('Location: memberinfo.php');       
    } else echo 'Delete failed. Try again';
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this and I am getting errors because of this `onClick = "deleterecord('".$fetch['userID']."');"` if I change it to `onClick = "deleterecord('.$fetch['userID'].');"` the errors go away but I am still getting id=undefined in my network console

Comment: try to pass static value and check value is getting or undefined. e.g: deleterecord('123'); @michealb

Comment: @michealb Maybe that `$fetch['userID']` has no value or null at all that's why you're getting an error.

Comment: yeah possible...:) @michealb

Answer (score 1):

This code will return `data-id` as required. Please modify below code as per your convenience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delete_button').on('click', function(){
       alert( $(this).closest('td').attr('data-id') );
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td data-id="456" >
    <button id="delete_button" >delete</button>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your HTML:

`<td data-id="<?php echo $fetch['userID']?>" >
    <button onClick = "deleterecord(<?php echo $fetch['userID']?>);">delete</button>
</td>`
 Now in JAvascript:

```
function deleterecord(deleteid) {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "deletemember.php",
            data: {id:deleteid},
            success: function () {
            }
        });
        $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
            opacity: "hide"
        }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
```